# Pulling an object out of a queue based on a data member

Tags: python, python-3.x, queue

I need to extend Queue so that I can pluck an object out of the Queue based on the value of one of the object's data members.

I've solved the problem like this and I wonder if I'm being dense.  Do I really need to do the list conversion to find the object?

```
class Datum:
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

class PluckQueue(Queue):

    def pluck(self, id):

        with self.not_empty:
            plucked = None
            while plucked is None:
                pluck_list = list(self.queue)
                try:
                    plucked = next(xx for xx in pluck_list if xx.id == id )
                except StopIteration:
                    plucked = None

                if plucked is None:
                    self.not_empty.wait()
                else:
                    index = pluck_list.index(plucked)
                    self.queue.remove(pluck_list[index])
             return plucked
    def __str__(self):
        return str([str(xx) for xx in self.queue])
pq = PluckQueue()
pq.put(Datum('a'))
pq.put(Datum('b'))
pq.put(Datum('c'))

plucked = pq.pluck('b')
print(plucked)
print(pq)
```

This gives the result:

```
b
['a', 'c']
```

Am I missing an easier way to do this?

Comment: Seems to defy the purpose of a queue, don't you think? If the number of possible "categories" is not too high you could work with sub-queues maybe?

Comment: Ours is not to reason why.

Answer (score 0):

This approach has worked fine and isn't so kludgy after all. The big difference one might make is to pass a predicate instead of having the test hardcoded into the next statement.